# Rigorously prove this elementary equation does not have any positive root

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis

Prove the following equation does not have a positive real-valued root for each $a\geq 1.5$ $$f(x)\equiv x-\left(1.05-0.05\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)^{2.5}=0.$$

Notice that the domain for real-valued $f(x)$ is $\left(a\sqrt{\frac{0.05}{1.05}},\infty\right)$. I computed $f'(x)$ and it reveals that $f(x)$ monotonely increases when $x$ is very large. But this does not help me to prove the assertion.

I attempted to take log on $f$ but that does not convert $f(x)$ into an algebraic function.

Comment: If you define $$f_p(x)\equiv x-\left(1.05-0.05\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)^{p},$$ it seems from graphs that $f_p(x)=0$ has no root in its domain for $2\le p\le 3$. It also seems possible that when $2\le p<p'\le3$, $f_p(x)<f_{p'}(x)$.  Maybe the exponent $2$ is more manageable, and there’s a way to prove these two observations individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take derivative of $f(x)$ and look for extreme points

$$
f^{'}=1-\left(1.05-0.05\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{4}\frac{a^2}{x^3}\right)=0
$$

It leads to equation
$$
x^{4}-1.05\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}x^{2}+0.05\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}a^{2}=0
$$

Solve for $x^2$
$$
x^2=\frac{1.05}{2}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}\pm\frac{\sqrt{D}}{2},\quad D=\left(\frac{a^2}{2}\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}\left(\frac{1.05^2}{2^{4/3}}-0.2a^{2/3}\right)
$$
For $a>\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1.05}{\sqrt{0.2}}\right)^3\approx3.236\quad D<0$, which means there is no real roots, hence function monotone on range of existense $\left(a\sqrt{\frac{0.05}{1.05}},\infty\right)$. We know that if $x\to\infty$ then $f(x)\to\infty$, while finite at lower boundary of $x$, thus function monotonely increases.

Last step is to check value at lower boundary. If it is higher than $0$ - there is no roots.
$$
f(x)=x=a\sqrt{\frac{0.05}{1.05}}>0
$$

****Extension****

Consider $
x^2=\frac{1.05}{2}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}\pm\frac{\sqrt{D}}{2},\quad D=\left(\frac{a^2}{2}\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}\left(\frac{1.05^2}{2^{4/3}}-0.2a^{2/3}\right)=\left(\frac{a^2}{2^2}\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}\left(1.05^2-0.2a^\frac{2}{3}2^\frac{4}{3}\right)
$

We are looking for only for positive $x$, thus can take only solution $x=\sqrt{\frac{1.05}{2}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}\pm\frac{\sqrt{D}}{2}}$

After factoring out: $x=\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}\sqrt{\frac{1.05}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{1.05^2-0.2(4a)^{2/3}}}{2}}$, both of these solutions exist on $0<a<\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1.05}{\sqrt{0.2}}\right)^3$

We know that for $a>0$ value of function at lower endpoint of $x$ is bigger than $0$. If we show that value of function at both extreme points obtained above bigger than $0$ (in case of minus sign needed only if respective $x>a\sqrt{\frac{0.05}{1.05}}$), then proof is done.

It's quite hard to substitute $x$ and solve obtained equations for $a$ analytically, so here is numerical methods come into play.

For positive sign: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((a%2F2)%5E(2%2F3)*sqrt(1.05%2F2+%2B+sqrt(1.05%5E2%2F4-0.05*(4*a)%5E(2%2F3))))+-+(1.05+-+0.05*a%5E2%2F((a%2F2)%5E(4%2F3)*(1.05%2F2+%2B+sqrt(1.05%5E2%2F4-0.05*(4*a)%5E(2%2F3)))))%5E(5%2F2)+%3D%3D+0

For negative sign: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((a%2F2)%5E(2%2F3)*sqrt(1.05%2F2+-+sqrt(1.05%5E2%2F4-0.05*(4*a)%5E(2%2F3))))+-+(1.05+-+0.05*a%5E2%2F((a%2F2)%5E(4%2F3)*(1.05%2F2+-+sqrt(1.05%5E2%2F4-0.05*(4*a)%5E(2%2F3)))))%5E(5%2F2)+%3D%3D+0

From where it comes that there is no real roots for $a$ bigger than some value near $1.34$, then obviously no real roots for $a>1.5$

Comment: I think the proof only works for $a>3.23566...$ in which $D<0$. For a counterexample, taking $a = 1.6$ you would get $D=0.163931...$ which is positive. Is there any way to fix your proof for each $a>1.5$?

Comment: Good point. I think there will be (most likely) two extreme points, so it will be required to determine one which is minimum and show that function at this point is bigger than zero